# How to Update DataGridView after adding column to database in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to add column to my database runtime using ALTER in sql server 
and when I want to show it or see the change in datagridview I have problem with that actually it doesn't change
here is my code:

```
    Dim con As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("StoreManager.My.MySettings.StoredbConnectionString").ConnectionString
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE dbo.Tables ADD newcolumn nchar(10);"
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    TablesTableAdapter.Fill(StoredbDataSet._Tables)
```

I even use the last line to update that but it doesn't work 
my table name is "Tables" and new column is "newcolumn"
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Datagirdview once alter statement execution and verify new column will be added.

try this it may helps!

```
    Dim Command As New SqlCommand()
    con.Open()
    Command = con.CreateCommand()
    Command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE detailssample ADD Address nvarchar(50) null"
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

Dim comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from detailssample", con)
con.Open()
Dim da1 As SqlDataAdapter
da1 = New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds1)
gvex.DataSource = ds1
gvex.DataBind()
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have added it to the `Table` in `SQL` the `Column` won't be in your `DataTable` in your `DataSet`. Which is where your `TableAdaptor` is getting the `Data` from to show in your `DataGridView` via (I would assume) a `BindingSource`.

Instead of setting the `DataSource` to a `BindingSource` you could use a `DataTable` instead, and fill it with an `SQL` statement in a `Sub`. You call just call that when you need to re fill the `DataTable` anytime.

```
Private Sub GetData()
    Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.StoredbConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Tables", con)
            con.Open()
            Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                myDataTable.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable
End Sub
```

Then when you add the new `Column` you can re fill the `DataTable`.

```
    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.StoredbConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE dbo.Tables ADD newcolumn nchar(10);", con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

    GetData()
```